# Script encrypted mail

Tags: powershell, encryption, powershell-3.0

Please help me with an PowerShell script to send an encrypted email on Outlook application.
I have a PowerShell script to send mail with attachments on Outlook application but want to encrypt that mail.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "mail"
$Mail.Subject = "Action"
$Mail.Body = "Hi Aviral, Good to see you"
$file = "C:\Users\a.raghorte\Desktop\UNIX\Utilization.txt"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($file)
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: Please add neccessary code to your question, not to comments

Comment: Maybe it's not a great idea to use your corporate email address as an example?

Comment: Do you want the client to server part encrypted (ie, using SSL/TLS and Submission) or do you want the server to server part encrypted (using ESMTP) or do you want the actual message encrypted (using PGP/GPG/etc) ?

Comment: You can say I want to digitally Sign that mail.

Comment: *I actually need the complete mail to be encrypted i.e. the subject body etc.* Mail encryption doesn't work that way. You can encrypt the body, but not the headers.

Comment: suggest me how to send an encrypted mail from outlook using PowerShell script.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Mail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003", 0x03)
```

That should do the trick while Outlook is running. If outlook is not running, the Mail goes to "Outbox" without signature/encryption.

0 = none, 1 = sign, 2 = encrypt, 3 = both